# Working with UIGrid and Typescript DefinitelyTyped

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ng-grid, definitelytyped

The new version of UI Grid (RC3) seems to have quite a few architectural changes from nggrid and the definitelytyped files for nggrid are giving me issues since they are of a different version.

Is there going to be a definitelytyped for the new version of uigrid?

Comment: One will exist if someone writes it. Be the change you want to see in the world.

Comment: ask the man in the mirror

Comment: Still no TypeScript definitions file for ui-grid?

Comment: not that i see, you can look https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped for all of the libraries that have a definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there going to be a definitelytyped for the new version of uigrid

Eventually. You can request it here : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/labels/Definition%3ARequest or and perhaps even ping the original authors directly : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/ng-grid/ng-grid.d.ts#L3

Comment: Looks like it has been added - https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/ui-grid

Answer (score 1):

Now you can obtain `typedefinition` of `ui grid` from two different sources whic is same work by Ben Tesser: https://github.com/btesser

[First one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ui-grid.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/0.0.7) is on nuget, [Second one](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/77bebbcc9df8b9965d6b7c7d388bfbac9f76b5f0/ui-grid/ui-grid.d.ts) is on github

First commit has been done at 8 Jul 2015

It may require some fixes.

In my case  adding these two fields in IGridOptions:

```
IGridOptions  {

        useExternalSorting?: boolean;
        enableGridMenu?: boolean; 
...
}
```